# How to find the error detail on Sharepoint Services 3?

Tags: sharepoint

I remembered that there is a log file that you can check for Sharepoint Services 3.0. I don't remember where I can find this. The reason I ask this I have an error when implementing the new template and it works on one, but not on the other machine. The error on the page is very generic: "The template you have choosen is invalid or can not be found".

Thanks

Comment: @Mitch: maybe not. He needs the log in order to diagnose a problem he has programming the SharePoint site (the new template).

Comment: SharePoint is particularly bad. It integrates the whole application stack so much you end up asking ServerFault-ish questions just doing your programming work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharePoint log files are usually in the "Logs" folder in the '[12 Hive](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/04/14/sharepoint-tip-31-do-you-know-the-12-hive-folder-structure-details.aspx)' which by default is in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Logs`.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to have the error displayed completely. You can enable this by modifying the web.config.

Find the SafeMode entry in your web.config and change CallStack="false" to CallStack="true". Then find the customErrors entry and set mode to mode="Off".
Now errors will be shown as a complete ASP.NET error screen

Comment: +1 this makes the debugging experiencce a lot easier than having to check the log file.